# parsing Javascript array or object with php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, parsing, object

I have a page that responds to javascript like this and I want to parse the 'series' array with php

```
$(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({

      series: [{
          name: 'IP',
          data: [3.09,3.24,3.33,]

      }, {
          name: 'IPK',
          data: [3.09,3.16,3.22,]

      }]
  });
});
```

what is the most effective method for doing that ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify( data )` -> `ajax`  ->  `json_decode` -> :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you have [json_decode](http://php.net/json-decode) to parse JSON data

```
var_dump(json_decode($series, true));
```

E.g.

```
  var output = {series: [{
      name: 'IP',
      data: [3.09,3.24,3.33,]

  }, {
      name: 'IPK',
      data: [3.09,3.16,3.22,]

  }];
  // Send output of JSON.stringify(output) to php via POST, GET or XHR.
```

And in php:

```
$input = json_decode($_GET['input'], true);
// $input = array('output' => 
               array('series' =>
                   array(
                       'name' => 'IP',
                       'data' => array(3.09, 3.24, 3.33)
                   ),
                   array(
                       'name' => 'IPK',
                       'data' => array(3.09, 3.16, 3.22)
                   )
               )
            );
```

Comment: I struggled hard and long for this answer and to understand this.  Remember in JS use ```JSON.stringify(obj)``` on json object together with ```json_decode($_GET['input'], true)``` in php.  They are not mutually exclusive but form a simbiose parsing relationship of two different languages and habitats.